# Extracting a pattern considering different patterns

Tags: r, regex, string, vector

Let's say I have this toy vectors

```
vec <- c("FOO blabla", "fail bla", "blabla FEEbla", "textFOO", "textttt")
to_match <- c("FOO", "FEE")
```

I would like to obtain a vector of the same length of `vec` in which to store only the patterns from `to_match`, if present, otherwise leave `NA`. Therefore, my desired result would be

```
c("FOO", NA, "FEE", "FOO", NA)
```

My first thought was to replace everything that *does not* match any of the patterns in `to_match` with whitespaces (`""`). I tried the following code which does the exact opposite, i.e. it replaces everything that *does* match any of the patterns in `to_match` with whitespaces.

```
sub(paste(to_match, collapse = "|"), "", vec)
# [1] " blabla"    "fail bla"   "blabla bla" "text"       "textttt"
```

However, I tried to invert this behaviour using a caret (`^`) before a grouping structure but with scarse success.

```
# fail
sub(paste0("^(", paste(to_match, collapse = "|"), ")"), "", vec)
# [1] " blabla"       "fail bla"      "blabla FEEbla" "textFOO"       "textttt"
```

How can I reach the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach was correct but you should look at extracting the pattern that you want instead of removing which you don't want.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(vec, str_c(to_match, collapse = "|"))
#[1] "FOO" NA    "FEE" "FOO" NA
```

Comment: Base-R equivalent: `regmatches(vec, gregexpr(paste0(to_match,collapse="|"), vec))`

Comment: Very clean solution with `stringr`, thanks @Ronak!

Comment: @DanielO Thanks for the base R solution, however that returns a list instead of a vector, and if I try `unlist` the `NA` entries disappear

Comment: Ronak's answer is certainly much cleaner, but there are ways in Base-R to manipulate the output. For instance, if you assign my last comment as `matches`. Then you could use `unlist(ifelse(lengths(matches) == 0,NA,matches))` to get your desired vector.

Comment: Got it, thanks @DanielO!